# Pattern recognition in finite array of numbers

Tags: regex

I was planning on using RegExes for a project that allows searching for opcode patterns in a set of Java bytecode instructions. My inputs will typically be between 10-65000 op codes long.

Here is an example of a pattern I would like to match: `0x1b 0x06 0x7c 0x3c`

I will sometimes need to be able to consider 2-6 opcodes as the same opcode which is why I am using regular expressions' character ranges. You can see examples of this in the first, second and fourth non-capturing groups in the following regex: `(?:0x1[a-d]) (?:0x0[3-8]) 0x7c (?:0x3[b-e])`

I know there must be a better way to do this! What sort of approach would be best for this type of input?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just convert each opcode to a `char`? It would take a bit of space to store, but not *that* much, and it would probably make pattern finding easier.

Comment: Alternative approach: match the 0x7c (which must match exactly) and on a hit scan forward and backward. BTW: since your input pattern contains no loops, you could even manually create a recogniser with some minor bit-twiddling.

Comment: @wildplasser I didn't use `+` or `?` in my example, but I would like to use that or something similar to it. I might translate strings to finite state machines and do something with that...

Comment: Constructing a DFA is what regexp does internally. But in your case the DFA looks quite trivial (no loops, no closure), I think I could hard-code it in a few minutes.

Comment: I do want to use loops though. I just omitted them from my example. I do not want to hardcode it because I want others to be able to easily create their own patterns to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if those bytes were stored as characters, I believe you can match them with a regex pattern like this:

```
[\x1a-\x1d][\x03-\x08]\x7c[\x3b-\x3e]
```

I'm not sure this is the most sensible approach, though.

Comment: I forgot that you can use hex for chars. I'd like something a bit faster, but I think this will work just fine.